# How is Optaplanner Works on 2 different solving with same data but different time

Tags: java, optaplanner

hi i have a data and i am solved this 2 times first is 25 minute and second is 1 minute. both solution's started score is same and rule file is same and solving method is same too (Simulated Annealing) but 
25 minute solved score is 0 hard / 22,251,950 medium / 22 normal 
and 
1 minute solved score is 0 hard / 22,251,920 / 27 normal
as you can see the lowest solving duration has the lowest score(better optimization) how this can be happen. Could you tell me how works optaplanner on this situation

Answer (score 0):

Simulated Annealing is far more fickle than Tabu Search and Late Acceptance. Every SA run can be different and changing the termination between 2 runs will greatly make them different. **For TS and LA (unlike for SA), a longer run will always have at least the same score as the shorter run (if nothing else has changed).**

That being said, the real problem is why the longer run didn't improve the medium score. Well, basically, **with the default move selectors it got stuck in a local optima** and (ironically) didn't have enough time to get out of it. The shorter run was just lucky. Probably the soft constraints are adversarial to the medium constraint.

The real solution is to add more course-grained move selectors, such as pillar moves or a custom move. Compare the 2 solutions and figure out which kind of move would be able to get the longer's result unstuck.